# Creating a menu resource in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, the menu resource is created automatically but In Android Studio I've heard you need to create it manually so I copy this function:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And XML resource:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

This doesn't automatically work and shows an error on line `android:showAsAction="never"`.

What's the different with it in Android Studio?

Comment: Which error getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the appcombat library, where showAsAction is in the app namespace, not android namespace. Change to

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

And add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your menu tag

Comment: How come it is not explained in [API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)? There it still says `android:showAsAction`..

Comment: @user963241 it may be a typo. It shows correctly in this guide https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html